# How to hold loop untill async function complete

Tags: node.js

I am facing problem while executing a async function inside a nested loop.
Below is my code

```
count1 = [1,2,3];
count2 = [1,2];
async.forEach(count1, function(count1, callback) {
    console.log("aa");
    async.forEach(count2, function(count2, callback1) {
        console.log("bb");
        connection.query('INSERT INTO customers set ?', data,function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback1(err);
            }
            console.log("success");
            callback1(null);
        }, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            callback1(err);
        });

    }, function(err) {
        callback(err);
    });
});
```

Below is the output of this code

```
aa
bb
bb
aa
bb
bb
aa
bb
bb
success
success
success
success
success
success
```

The expected output should be

```
aa
bb
success
bb
success
aa
bb
success
bb
success
aa
bb
success
bb
success
```

Please suggest how can i implement a async function that hold the loop untill the function complete its execution.

Answer (score -1):

```
count1 = [1,2,3];
count2 = [1,2];
async.forEach(count1, function(count1, callback){
    console.log("aa");
    async.forEach(count2, function(count2, callback1){
        console.log("bb");
        connection.query('INSERT INTO customers set ?', data,function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback1(err);
            }
            console.log("success")
            callback1(null);
        }, function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
            callback1(err);
        });   
    }, function(err){
        callback(err);
    });
}, function(err){
    callback(err);
});
```